# Guardar array en MySQL sin utilizar loop

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo una página para guardar notas de venta en MySql, ya es funcional pero me da curiosidad si no hay una forma más rápida de hacerlo sin tener que hacer un query por cada elemento del array que necesito guardar. Mi código actual:

```
    <?php      
    include('loginphp.php');  
    $mygetter = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $values = json_decode($mygetter); 
    $size = count($values);
    define('url_base', '//'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    
     for ($x = 1; $x < $size; $x++) {
        $ciudad = $values[$x][0]->Ciudad;
        $estado = $values[$x][0]->Estado;
        $puntodeventa = $values[$x][0]->PuntoDeVenta;
        $fecha = $values[$x][0]->Fecha;
        $nota = $values[$x][0]->Nota;
        $cantidad = $values[$x][0]->Unidades;
        $producto = $values[$x][0]->Producto;
        $precioUnitario = $values[$x][0]->PrecioUnitario;
        $subtotal = $values[$x][0]->Subtotal;
        $operacion = $values[$x][0]->Operacion;
        $observacion = $values[$x][0]->Observaciones;
        $metodoPago = $values[$x][0]->FormaDePago;
        
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas (ciudad, estado, puntodeventa, fecha, nota, cantidad, producto, precioUnitario, subtotal, operacion, observacion, metodoPago)
VALUES ('$ciudad', '$estado', '$puntodeventa', '$fecha', '$nota', '$cantidad', '$producto', '$precioUnitario', '$subtotal', '$operacion', '$observacion', '$metodoPago')";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "Correctamente Guardado";
    
    
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
        
    }     
?>
```

Con notas de 4-5 elementos es muy rápido, pero con 30-40 se hace medio tardado, ¿hay alguna forma más eficiente de hacerlo?
Gracias

Comment: Precisamente para eso son las [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, la hay. Puedes insertarlo todo en un solo insert guardando los valores a insertar en un array y luego concatenándolos:

```
<?php      
    include('loginphp.php');  
    $mygetter = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $values = json_decode($mygetter); 
    $size = count($values);
    define('url_base', '//'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    $insertValues = [];
    
     for ($x = 1; $x < $size; $x++) {
        $ciudad = $values[$x][0]->Ciudad;
        $estado = $values[$x][0]->Estado;
        $puntodeventa = $values[$x][0]->PuntoDeVenta;
        $fecha = $values[$x][0]->Fecha;
        $nota = $values[$x][0]->Nota;
        $cantidad = $values[$x][0]->Unidades;
        $producto = $values[$x][0]->Producto;
        $precioUnitario = $values[$x][0]->PrecioUnitario;
        $subtotal = $values[$x][0]->Subtotal;
        $operacion = $values[$x][0]->Operacion;
        $observacion = $values[$x][0]->Observaciones;
        $metodoPago = $values[$x][0]->FormaDePago;
        
        $insertValues[] = "('$ciudad', '$estado', '$puntodeventa', '$fecha', '$nota', '$cantidad', '$producto', '$precioUnitario', '$subtotal', '$operacion', '$observacion', '$metodoPago')";
    }     

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas (ciudad, estado, puntodeventa, fecha, nota, cantidad, producto, precioUnitario, subtotal, operacion, observacion, metodoPago)
VALUES " . implode(',', $insertValues) . ";";

    if (count($insertValues) > 0 && mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo "Correctamente Guardado";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
?>
```